# How to prioritize a variable (Python)

Tags: python

Okay so I have been having a problem making a variable prioritized without anything to do with length. I want Excellence credits to be prioritized because it his the highest value credit in NCEA then after I want it to prioritize Merit and then achieved until it picks the best 80 credits

I've only seen example so far about using max() which is not what I need

```
#Ncea Calculator
EXCELLENCE_THRESHOLD = 50
MERIT_THRESHOLD = 50

user_input_achieved = input("How many NCEA achieved credits do you have: ")
total_achieved_credits = int(user_input_achieved)

user_input_merit = input("How many NCEA merit credits do you have: ")
total_merit_credits = int(user_input_merit)

user_input_excellence = input("How many NCEA excellence credits do you have: ")
total_excellence_credits = int(user_input_excellence)

excellence_endorsement_applies = False
if total_excellence_credits >= EXCELLENCE_THRESHOLD:
   excellence_endorsement_applies = True

merit_endorsement_applies = False
if total_merit_credits + total_excellence_credits >= MERIT_THRESHOLD:
   merit_endorsement_applies = True

print('You have a total of', total_achieved_credits + total_merit_credits + total_excellence_credits ,'NCEA credits')

if excellence_endorsement_applies == True:
   print("You also got an overall excellence endorsement, well done!")

if merit_endorsement_applies == True and excellence_endorsement_applies == False:
   print("You got an overall merit endorsement, well done but there's still room for improvement!")

total_credits_this_year = total_achieved_credits + total_merit_credits + total_excellence_credits

if total_credits_this_year >= int(80):
   print("You passed Ncea Level 1!")

if total_credits_this_year < int(79):
   print("You failed Ncea Level 1, come on man!")

rank_score_achieved = int(user_input_achieved) * int(2)
rank_score_merit = int(user_input_merit) * int(3)
rank_score_excellence = int(user_input_excellence) * int(4)

total_rank_score = rank_score_achieved + rank_score_merit + rank_score_excellence

print ('your total rank score is', total_rank_score)
```

So If a user wrote:

```
How many achieved credits:20
How many merit credits:30
How many excellence credits:50
```

then I would want it to pick the best 80 so it would pick 50 excellence then 30 merit credits and then calculate the rank score.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "prioritize a variable". Do you mean you want to sort the variables alphabetically by variable name?

Comment: I second @takendarkk; who or what is prioritizing or selecting variables? Are you sorting?

Comment: This is one of the most confusing problem statements I've come across. For what purpose would you want to prioritize statements by variable name? This is starting to sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/393532).

Comment: Okay I was struggling to explain so I typed my actual code so I want it to prioritize excellence credits over merit and it to prioritize merit credits over achieved unit it reaches the best 80 credits.

Answer (score 0):

This was hard to understand but I believe the OP is simply trying to sum up values until they reach 80 using the `name` as the sort index.
Traditionally you would store these `name:value` pairs in a dictionary, not variables, e.g.:

```
data = {'a': 60, 'b': 30, 'c': 50, 'd': 20}
```

Then you can simply iterate over the `sorted()` dictionary until you get to your total, e.g.:

```
In []:
results = []
total = 0
for k in sorted(data, reverse=True):
    total += data[k]
    if total >= 80:
        results.append((k, data[k]+80-total))
        break
    results.append((k, data[k]))
results

Out[]:
[('d', 20), ('c', 50), ('b', 10)]
```

Comment: Okay I was struggling to explain so I wrote my actual code so I want it to prioritize excellence credits over merit and it to prioritize merit credits over achieved